# How to elegantly express that "no money was required"

Tags: expressions

I need a **catchy title** for my lecture which will emphasize that no goverment money were used. I came with something like this, but it is *little clumsy*.

> Searching for "X" in "Y":**a study which costed 0 €**

Is there some **better or more elegant way** how write it? I would prefer a title which will contain "0 €".

Comment: *no money required* and *no money used* are two different things!

Comment: For something catchy, how about this: *Searching for "X" in "Y": Not a (single) euro spent!*

Comment: It doesn't contain €0, but one possibility would be: _Searching for "X" in "Y" **at no cost**._ The phrase "at no cost" is a common way of expressing that no money was exchanged between two parties. If you really want €0, you can simply use the preposition _for_: _Searching for "X" in "Y" for €0_.

Comment: Note that the past tense of *cost* in this sense *have a cost of* is *cost*. *Costed* is employed only with the sense *project the cost of*: "We costed the study at €800 and in the end spent €780."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, money is a *mass noun*, so you use it as a singular: no money *was* required, no government money *was* used.

Maulik V is correct in noting that there is a difference between *money used* and *money required*, by the way. However, I think that is not a problem in this case.

To express the idea that the study did not cost money, you can say it was done for **free**, but since you want to include the actual costs of €0 that is not an option.

An amount in euro is usually written in the same way as an amount in dollars, by the way, with the amount following the currency sign.

You could try something along the lines of:

> A study performed at a cost of €0.
>   A study at €0 investment
>   Searching for "X" in "Y": how a €0 investment yields results.

I originally wrote €0.-, but as @Steve Melnikoff noted:

> [W]hile using a hyphen to indicate no cents (or no pennies, if we're using pounds) is not uncommon, it's not normally printed like that. So this should appear as "€0.00", or just "€0".

Comment: Using a comma to mark the decimal point is not correct in English; a period should be used. Also, while using a hyphen to indicate no cents (or no pennies, if we're using pounds) is not uncommon, it's not normally printed like that. So this should appear as "€0.00", or just "€0".

Comment: I'd also suggest that the first example should be "A study performed at **a** cost of €0", not "the".

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: You are right about the decimal point (and I am ashamed I made the mistake), I have included your correct advice on writing amounts without cents in my answer, and I also agree with your _the_ - > _a_ remark. Thanks you :)

Comment: The decimal comma *is* used in some English-speaking nations, for example South Africa.

Comment: Typo: To express **they** idea

Comment: @starsplusplus You're right :) Feel free to edit such glaring typos :)

Comment: @oerkelens Normally I would but it seemed too small an edit when there wasn't a problem with the rest of the post. I'd have had to find some other characters to change to take me to the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

I would focus on spending.  Try something like this:

**"Searching for X in Y -- without spending money"**

or

**"Searching for X in Y -- without spending €"**